# ServiceStack Serviceless for CQRS

Tags: servicestack, cqrs

I would like to be able to leverage ServiceStacks routing and built in documentation functionality to expose service operations based on the message type annotation with route and verb. A generic Service will simply delegate the received request to another Request Handling service.

eg.
Give I have the following type and configured routes with verb for each
     public class Request{}

```
 [Route("/order", "POST")]
 public class PlaceOrder : Request { }

 [Route("/order/{id}", "GET")]
 public class OrderDetailsCriteria : Request {
     Guid OrderId { get; set; }
 }

 public class OrderDetails { }

 [Route("/inventoryItem/{id}", "PATCH")]
 public class ReduceInventory : Request {
     Guid InventoryItemId { get; set; }
 }
```

I would like to create a simple service that will deal with all these but at the same time only allow the verbs as configured in the types attribute
something like:

```
public class MyService : Service {
    public void Post(Request request) {
        RequestService.Send(request);
    }

    public void Patch(Request request) { 
        RequestService.Send(request);
    }

    public object Get(Request request) {
        return RequestService.Send(request);
    }
}
```

Essentially I do not want to have to create a service or each set of Request types because each method will effectively be doing the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a single implementation to handle all Verbs for a request by using the `Any()` method, e.g:

```
public object Any(MyRequest request)
{
    var verb = base.Request.Verb; //if needed
    ...
    RequestService.Send(request);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Yes my first thought was to do that but I do not get metadata operation documentation. So I assume ServiceStack must be using reflection over Services in order to discover types to be able to generate the docs

Comment: @RicardodaSilva I'd also strongly recommend adding `IReturn<T>` or `IReturnVoid` markers to Request DTO's, these provide metadata info, strong typing and a nice API for your Service Clients.